# Installed Kubernetes on Ubuntu and I see a lot of nodes are getting created in MAAS

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-server

After installing kubernetes, I see a huge list of nodes and yet still increasing (whats going on?):

aware-code
aware-yak
casual-corgi
casual-whale
casual-mole
clear-hound
close-liger
cool-troll
decent-beetle
divine-bug
driven-drake
easy-cod
equal-frog
equal-swan
exotic-earwig
expert-cow
expert-slug
fair-bee
first-dog
frank-monkey
gentle-racer
good-koi
grown-bunny
guided-eft
handy-wahoo
hip-hornet
holy-bass
holy-hen
intent-bear
large-kit

I can't find that list on Kubernetes, but I can see it in MAAS (since I started setting up Kubernetes, I've been watching MAAS so I know that this started since installing Kubernetes)

Here are all of the pods that I have (installed by default with Kubernetes) if anyone can really know if any of this is causing this
[image]

And here is the list of VMs that has been created after Kubernetes installation (there are a lot more than that)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, the way that `conjure-up canonical-kubernetes` works is: conjure-up drives Juju and asks it to deploy the cluster to whatever the appropriate cloud is (in this case, MAAS), Juju then asks MAAS to give it machines (or, in this case, spin up VMs) for each node needed to run the cluster, Juju then deploys the appropriate charm code for each application to the VMs, and finally the charm code installs and configures the appropriate kubernetes or other components for the role that that VM is playing in the cluster.

The "try was stopped" error from conjure-up is originally coming from Juju, probably due to the VMs being stopped out from under it.  Manually running `juju list-models` might provide some more info there, but I certainly would expect Juju to provide a better error message than that.

As for where the VMs came from in the first place, it's hard to say without more info.  The conjure-up logs (in `~/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log`) would be very helpful.  Is it possible that you ran `conjure-up` multiple times?  Each time you ran that, it would create a new model in Juju with a new deployment of Kubernetes, which would take up ~8 new VMs.  If you encountered some error when running `conjure-up`, it may still have started the cluster but failed watching for it to become ready or in doing one of the post-processing steps.  Again, that info would be in the `conjure-up.log` file.

Once you have started a deployment, you can use `juju list-models` and `juju status -m <model-name>` to check the status of the deployment using Juju.  This will provide details about exactly which machines the cluster is using for which units, as well as what the status of each of those machines according to the charm (i.e., whether it's successfully participating in the cluster).